# ExtJS 3.4 - How to prevent user clicking outside a window?

Tags: extjs, focus, extjs3

In my application I have an `Ext.Window` component that gets created when a user clicks a button. While this window is open I do not want the user to be able to click anywhere outside of this window until either the window is closed or submitted, similar to how an `Ext.LoadMask` freezes everything on the page. I can successfully create the window and I think the correct method that I am looking for is the `focus()` method, but this isn't working for me. It has no effect at all.

I'm wondering if I am doing something wrong, if I've mistaken the purpose of the `focus()` method, or if there is another way of achieving what I am trying to do. Below is my code:

```
var window = new Ext.Window({
  title: 'Specify rezoning details',
  layout: 'fit',
  closable: false,
  width: 300,
  height: 200,
  items: [zoningCombo],
  buttons: [submitButton, cancelButton]
});
window.show(); //This works
window.focus(); //THIS DOES NOT WORK TO PREVENT INPUT ELSEWHERE
```

Thanks for any help.

R

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specify `modal: true` in your configuration for the window.

Reference: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Window-cfg-modal